# Distinguish between Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V versions

Tags: windows, wix, installation, hyper-v

I'm writing an installer and need to be able to differentiate between machines running Windows Server 2012 with the Hyper-V feature enabled and the "baremetal" Hyper-V version, Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012.

For those who are unsure of the difference, this thread more or less covers it:

[Hyper-V Server 2012 vs Windows Server 2012 Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539308/hyper-v-server-2012-vs-windows-server-2012-standard)

They both seem to have the same version/build numbers so checking this isn't much use. I'm guessing I need to do either a registry lookup or a WMI call but I don't know where to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the OperatingSystemSKU method of the WMI Win32_OperatingSystem class.

The value should be 0x2A (decimal 42) for Hyper-V Server, I believe.